# How to get the type of something in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the line of code below from a tutorial I am following, but with my version of Flutter this syntax is wrong:

I am using Flutter 1.7.8 and the tutorial is using 0.11.2, so I guess this is an issue with my version of Dart.

```dart
final type = _typeOf<BlocProvider<T>>();
```

How can I convert the code above to the latest version of Dart?

Comment: That should work. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @RémiRousselet because VSCode throws an error "The method '_typeof' isn´t defined for the class."

Comment: there's no _typeof method in Dart (and this would be a private name anyway). Have you tried `thing.runtimeType`?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why can't you use `BlocProvider<T>` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_typeOf` isn't part of the language. You have to implement it yourself.

It's fairly straightforward:

```dart
Type _typeOf<T>() => T;
```